# Carrito de compras: no se guarda la información en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli, session, insert

Estoy trabajando por primera vez en un proyecto con un Carrito de compras con Sesiones y quiero que se inserten los registros obtenidos a través del arreglo en mi tabla de 'compras' pero no puedo hacerlo.

Dejo el código de sopping-cart.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'Connections/conexion2.php';
  if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
          $arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];
          $encontro=false;
          $numero=0;
          for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){
            if($arreglo[$i]['Id']==$_GET['id']){
              $encontro=true;
              $numero=$i;
            }
          }
          if($encontro==true){
            $arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']=$arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']+1;
            $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
          }else{
            $nombre="";
            $precio=0;
            $imagen="";
             include ("Connections/conexion2.php");
       $re=("SELECT * from productos where id=".$_GET['id'])or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $query=mysqli_query($con,$re);
            while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
              $nombre=$f['nombre'];
              $precio=$f['precio'];
              $imagen=$f['imagen'];
            }
            $datosNuevos=array('Id'=>$_GET['id'],
                    'Nombre'=>$nombre,
                    'Precio'=>$precio,
                    'Imagen'=>$imagen,
                    'Cantidad'=>1);

            array_push($arreglo, $datosNuevos);
            $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;

          }
    }




  }else{
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
      $nombre="";
      $precio=0;
      $imagen="";
     include ("Connections/conexion2.php");
       $re=("SELECT * from productos where id=".$_GET['id'])or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $query=mysqli_query($con,$re);
            while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $nombre=$f['nombre'];
        $precio=$f['precio'];
        $imagen=$f['imagen'];
      }
      $arreglo[]=array('Id'=>$_GET['id'],
              'Nombre'=>$nombre,
              'Precio'=>$precio,
              'Imagen'=>$imagen,
              'Cantidad'=>1);
      $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
    }
  }
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  global $con;
$theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($con,$theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO compras (name, email, telefono, direccion, cp, ciudad, formadepago) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['telefono'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['direccion'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cp'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ciudad'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['formadepago'], "text"));


  $Result1 = mysqli_query($con,$insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  $insertGoTo = "carritoadd.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>
CARRITOADD.PHP
<?php
session_start();
include ('Connections/conexion2.php');
$arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];

    $numeroventa=0;
    $re=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from compras order by numeroventa DESC limit 1");
   $query=mysqli_query($con,$re);
            while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          $numeroventa=$f['numeroventa']; 
    }
    if($numeroventa==0){
      $numeroventa=1;
    }else{
      $numeroventa=$numeroventa+1;
    }
    for($i=0; $i<count($arreglo);$i++){
      mysqli_query("UPDATE compras SET (numeroventa, imagen,nombre,precio,cantidad,subtotal) values(
    ".$numeroventa.",
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Imagen']."',
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Nombre']."', 
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Precio']."',
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']."',
    '".($arreglo[$i]['Precio']*$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad'])."'
    )"); 
    }
    unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
    header("Location: pedidook");
?>
```

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda si colocas el error también

Comment: Hola GDPD, el error es que recorre todo el código pero no inserta los datos en la tabla. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Imprime el error de la consulta colocando `echo mysqli_error($con);` después de `mysqli_query` así sabrás donde está el problema

Comment: Al hacer un var_dump($_SESSION['carrito']) te muestra los datos que deseas insertar? El problema no está en el código que muestras sino en el envió de datos o en la BBDD.

Comment: Edité la pregunta colocando el código de ambas paginas para facilitar su observación. Gracias por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes optimizar tu codigo seleccionando unicamente el "numeroventa" en el select. Pero lo que necesitas realmente no es actualizar, es insertar.
En la configuración de la tabla "compras" coloca "numeroventa" como **UNIQUE** y **AUTO-INCREMENT**.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('Connections/conexion2.php');
$arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];
if (count($arreglo) > 0) {
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO compras (imagen,nombre,precio,cantidad,subtotal) VALUES ";
    foreach($arreglo as $i => $val){
        $insertSQL .= "('".$val['Imagen']."',
            '".$val['Nombre']."', 
            '".$val['Precio']."',
            '".$val['Cantidad']."',
            '".($val['Precio']*$val['Cantidad'])."'),";
    }
    $insertSQL = substr_replace($insertSQL, ";", -1);//reemplazamos el ultimo , por ;
    mysqli_query($insertSQL);
}
unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
header("Location: pedidook");
?>
```

> Una alternativa sin usar el campo "numeroventa" como unico y auto-incrementado.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('Connections/conexion2.php');
$arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];
if (count($arreglo) > 0) {
    $numeroventa=0;
    $re=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT numeroventa from compras order by numeroventa DESC limit 1");
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$re);
    while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $numeroventa=$f['numeroventa']; 
    }
    $numeroventa++; // Incrementamos en 1. Si no existe el primer registro = 1
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO compras (numeroventa, imagen,nombre,precio,cantidad,subtotal) VALUES ";
    foreach($arreglo as $i => $val){
        $insertSQL .= "(".$numeroventa.",
            '".$val['Imagen']."',
            '".$val['Nombre']."', 
            '".$val['Precio']."',
            '".$val['Cantidad']."',
            '".($val['Precio']*$val['Cantidad'])."'),";
        $numeroventa++;
    }
    $insertSQL = substr_replace($insertSQL, ";", -1);//reemplazamos el ultimo , por ;
    mysqli_query($insertSQL);
}
unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
header("Location: pedidook");
?>
```

Comment: La segunda opción sin tracsacciones es bastante problematica.

Comment: En ambas opciones sigo sin poder grabar estos datos en la bd. Paso a explicar el funcionamiento pretendido:
Tengo el archivo "sopping-cart.php" dónde se muestran los productos agregados al "carrito", en el mismo archivo tengo un formulario donde primero hago insert con los datos del usuario (solicitando su nombre, correo, etc) y luego envía a carritoadd.php para modificar ese registro agregando los datos de los productos previamente agregados al carrito.